# Android (maven) recreates "gen" folder automatically.Can't run project

Tags: android, maven

I have moved my project to maven.
Firstly it appeared in eclipse as "java project". I have made it look like android project (to be able to build and deploy not just from terminal) but faced such a problem:
It spams into console with the following message:

> [2011-09-16 15:23:34 - ****-maven] /****-maven/gen already exists but is not a source folder. Convert to a source folder or rename it.

It shouldn't be used at all. Because there is already /target/generated-source/r folder with a needed  class. After deleting "gen" folder it is instantly recreated. Also this folder automatically appears in "Build-path" properties. 
Here is a screenshot of build-path property - http://d.pr/jMJ6 .

I still can use "mvn android:deploy" and then connect debugger manually but that is not comfortable and errors in eclipse drive me crazy.

I have already tried clean install, eclipse:eclipse, etc.

UPDATE: 
I thought that all problems were because of "gen" folder. 
The real problem was in wrong pom.xml configuration.
I had

```
<configuration>
                <sdk>
                    <path>src</path>
                    <platform>8</platform>
                </sdk>
```

instead of

```
<configuration>
                <sdk>
                    <path></path>
                    <platform>8</platform>
                </sdk>
```

Comment: Are you using the maven-eclipse-plugin? Don't you use m2e or m2eclipse? You shouldn't use maven-eclipse-plugin anymore...Which Eclipse version do you use?

Comment: I have both, however I have deleted maven-eclipse-plugin settings from pom.xml. Version: Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Indigo Release
Build id: 20110615-0604

Comment: Which version of the m2e-android connector are you using?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use Intellij IDEA. It is more developer-friendly :)
I needed just couple of minutes to run the project there. No additional plugins, no more headache